# Java: Abstract class constructors and this()

Tags: java, constructor, this, abstract

Can someone point out what I'm misunderstanding?

I've got two classes, an Abstract and a Concrete, as follows:

```
public abstract class Abstract
{
    protected static int ORDER = 1;

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Concrete c = new Concrete("Hello");
    }

    public Abstract()
    {
        Class c = this.getClass();
        System.out.println(ORDER++ + ": Class = " 
            + c.getSimpleName() 
            + "; Abstract's no-arg constructor called.");
    }

    public Abstract(String arg)
    {
        this();
        Class c = this.getClass();
        System.out.println(ORDER++ + ": Class = " 
            + c.getSimpleName() 
            + "; Abstract's 1-arg constructor called.");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Concrete extends Abstract
{
   public Concrete()
   {
      super();
      Class c = this.getClass();
      System.out.println(ORDER++ + ": Class = " 
          + c.getSimpleName() 
          + "; Concrete's no-arg constructor called.");
   }

   public Concrete(String arg)
   {
      super(arg);
      Class c = this.getClass();
      System.out.println(ORDER++ + ": Class = " 
          + c.getSimpleName() 
          + "; Concrete's 1-arg constructor called.");
   }
}
```

When I run this I get the following output:

> 1) Class = Concrete; Abstract's no-arg
>   constructor called.
>   2) Class =
>   Concrete; Abstract's 1-arg constructor
>   called.
>   3) Class = Concrete;
>   Concrete's 1-arg constructor called.

My question is this: why doesn't the call to this() from Abstract's String arg constructor call this no-arg constructor on Concrete? Or, perhaps more pertinently, is there any way to get Abstract's String arg constructor to call the no-arg constructor on Concrete, allowing a "proper" chaining of Constructors?

Answer (score 7):

No - constructor chaining *always* goes either sideways (in the same type) or upwards (to the parent type).

Don't forget that the call has to be resolved at *compile-time* - and `Abstract` doesn't know what other classes are going to derive from it, or what constructors they'll have.

You *could* call a virtual method within the `Abstract` constructor, and override that method within `Concrete`... but I would urge you *not* to do that. In particular, the constructor body for `Concrete` won't have been executed yet, and neither will the variable initializers - so it wouldn't be able to do anything with `Concrete`-specific state. There are some *very* specific situations where that's the correct thing to do, but they're rare and should be handled with caution.

What are you actually trying to do? Usually I find it's better to have many "sideways" chains leading to a single constructor which has the "upward" chain.

Comment: Thanks Jon. The fact that getClass knows the Object isa Concrete, but this() calls the Abstract no-arg constructor is what seems a little unnatural to me.

The chaining I was trying to achieve would seem to me to have allowed a more natural division of responsibility between constructors.  I think I'll have to duplicate code in Concrete's constructors, or move it out into a new method, but since I'm not writing all the Concrete implementations of this Abstract class, that's something I'll have to document for the other developers.

Comment: So you were trying to treat constructors as if they were virtual methods? Yeah, that's not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

That's simply the way it is (as detailed by Jon Skeet).

You could add an init block to Concrete though:

```
{
  Class c = this.getClass();
  System.out.println(ORDER++ + ": Class = " 
  + c.getSimpleName() 
   + "; Concrete's init block called.");
}
```

In contrast to the default constructor, the inizializer block is always called:

```
1: Class = Concrete; Abstract's no-arg constructor called.
2: Class = Concrete; Abstract's 1-arg constructor called.
3: Class = Concrete; Concrete's init block called.
4: Class = Concrete; Concrete's 1-arg constructor called.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [post](http://coffeewithcode.com/2011/07/27/what-the-need-of-constructor-in-abstract-class/) which focus on what the need of abstract class and how it works.May this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should have to know that a child class is always hidden from the parent class. You can't call the method or constructor of child class directly like you did in child class.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to handle this is generally to have all constructors for a class end up using one common constructor, i.e.:

```
public Abstract() {
  this(null);
}
public Abstract(String arg) {
  // do all Abstract init here
}

public Concrete() {
  this(null);
}
public Concrete(String arg) {
  super(arg);
  // do all Concrete init here
}
```